# char* decimal to hexadecimal in little-endian

Tags: c, hex, endianness

I have an issue where I am inputting an decimal argument to my code:

```
./a.out 650
```

and would like to simply convert the decimal value into hex and output it in a little-endian format:

```
0A28
```

My current solution has been to convert the char* to decimal using atoi (we can assume the input is decimal, no worry about error cases).

I have read that I could create an int* and cast it to the char*, something like this:

```
char* bar = argv[1];
int* foo = (char*)&bar;
```

and that iterating through it would produce the solution I needed, but I do not quite understand how that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long int n = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);
unsigned char const * p = (unsigned char const *)&n;

for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof n; ++i)
    printf("%02X", p[i]);
```

To print the reverse endianness, use `sizeof n - i - 1` in place of `i`.

Comment: Thank you, I've never heard of strtoul before. I'll look into that and see if I can learn why instead of just how.

Answer (score 2):

This should take the program's first parameter and print it out as a big endian hexadecimal number and little endian hexadecimal.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) return -1;
  char *endptr;
  unsigned long d = strtoul(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
  if (*endptr) {
    printf("Not a decimal number '%s'\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
  }
  printf("%lX\n", d);  // normal
  do {
   printf("%02hhX", (unsigned char) d);  // little endian first
    d >>= 8;
  } while (d);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```